# Python - Extract multiple json with the same key

Tags: python, json

So I am loading a JSON file containing a proxies,

my JSON Object .

```
 {  
   "http":{  
      "http://":"64.90.50.38:45876/",
      "http://":"89.250.220.40:54687/",
      "http://":"89.207.92.146:37766/",
      "http://":"89.23.194.174:8080/",
      "http://":"82.208.111.100:52480/"
   }
}
```

I want to access each proxy but I keep getting the last proxy which is
"http://":"82.208.111.100:52480/

my code :

```
import json
x = open('proxy.json', 'r')
data = json.load(x)
print data['http']
```

My Question is : 
how can I access these values with the same key ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#repeated-names-within-an-object)

The RFC specifies that the names within a JSON object should be unique, but does not mandate how repeated names in JSON objects should be handled. By default, this module does not raise an exception; instead, it ignores all but the last name-value pair for a given name:

```
>>> weird_json = '{"x": 1, "x": 2, "x": 3}'
>>> json.loads(weird_json)
{'x': 3}
```

The `object_pairs_hook` parameter can be used to alter this behavior.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) also state that `object_pairs_hook` is an optional function that will be called with the result of any object literal decoded with an ordered list of pairs. The return value of `object_pairs_hook` will be used instead of the dict. This feature can be used to implement custom decoders. If `object_hook` is also defined, the `object_pairs_hook` takes priority.

For example,

```
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>>
>>> s = """
... {
...    "http":{
...       "http://":"64.90.50.38:45876/",
...       "http://":"89.250.220.40:54687/",
...       "http://":"89.207.92.146:37766/",
...       "http://":"89.23.194.174:8080/",
...       "http://":"82.208.111.100:52480/"
...    }
... }
... """
>>>
>>> def custom_hook(obj):
...     # Identify dictionary with duplicate keys...
...     # If found create a separate dict with single key and val and as list.
...     if len(obj) > 1 and len(set(i for i, j in obj)) == 1:
...         data_dict = defaultdict(list)
...         for i, j in obj:
...             data_dict[i].append(j)
...         return dict(data_dict)
...     return dict(obj)
...
>>> data = json.loads(s, object_pairs_hook=custom_hook)
>>> pprint(data)
{'http': {'http://': ['64.90.50.38:45876/',
                      '89.250.220.40:54687/',
                      '89.207.92.146:37766/',
                      '89.23.194.174:8080/',
                      '82.208.111.100:52480/']}}
>>>
>>> pprint(data['http'])
{'http://': ['64.90.50.38:45876/',
             '89.250.220.40:54687/',
             '89.207.92.146:37766/',
             '89.23.194.174:8080/',
             '82.208.111.100:52480/']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys. If there are duplicate keys in the definition of the dictionary, the last `key:value` pair will be used.

The JSON object is converted to a Python dictionary by `json.load`.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to have a data structure that supports holding multiple values. For example

```
{  
   "http": [
      "64.90.50.38:45876",
      "89.250.220.40:54687",
      "89.207.92.146:37766",
      "89.23.194.174:8080",
      "82.208.111.100:52480"
   ]
}
```

Your code would then print
`["64.90.50.38:45876", "89.250.220.40:54687", ...]`

Django, for example, has `MultiValueDict` that you can then load your data into to provide a nicer API. The source can be found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/utils/datastructures/).

Answer (score 0):

Too slow, but if you can change the JSON, why not make it a list?

```
{  
   "http": [
       "64.90.50.38:45876",
       "89.250.220.40:54687",
       "89.207.92.146:37766",
       "89.23.194.174:8080",
       "82.208.111.100:52480"
   ]
}
```

You can then parse the data as follows:

```
with open('proxy.json', 'r) as json_data:
    proxy_data = json.load(json_data)
```

And access it:

```
proxy_data['http'][0]

>>> 'http://64.90.50.38:45876/'
```